# Json.Net boolean parsing issue

Tags: json, json.net

JObject.Parse(jsonString) is causing issue for boolean data. e.g. The json is :

```
{
    "BoolParam": true
}
```

I used the following code to parse:

```
JObject data = JObject.Parse(str1);
foreach (var x in data)
{
  string name = x.Key;
  Console.Write(name + " (");
  JToken value = x.Value;
  Console.Write(value.Type + ")\n");
  Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

This print out the value as :
BoolParam (Boolean) : **True**

The case sensitivity causes issue as I save this json for later use. The saved json looks like

```
{
    "BoolParam": True
}
```

However, when i later use it, the JObject.Parse(str) throws error as invalid Json :Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: T. Path 'BoolParam', line 2, position 15.

If I change the case from "True" to "true", it works. I dont want to add this hack to change the case when saving but is there a better way to handle this scenario.

Comment: Actually, your issue is in the `Console.Write()` method, which tries to conveniently print your `JTokenType.Boolean` value. If you want to properly serialize/deserialize json in c#, just use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` and `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>()`, which will properly output boolean values, as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I dont want to add this hack to change the case when saving but is
>   there a better way to handle this scenario.

No, you have to produce valid JSON when saving if you want to be able to later deserialize it with a JSON serializer such as Newtonsoft JSON. So fixing your saving routing is the right way to go here.

Comment: I do understand that I would have to save a valid json. The thing that causing issue is when i parse i get the value as "True" but valid Json string expects "true". So wondering is there a way to parse it as "true"

Comment: @surya If your JSON contains `True` then it is not valid JSON; it's as simple as that.  The `true` token MUST be all lower case.  See section 2.1 of the [JSON spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627).  As Darin said, you need to fix the way you are saving the JSON if you expect a parser to be able to read it correctly.

Comment: I Added the fix but i think i failed to explain earlier.. Its not me who is changing the boolean value to "True" but Json.net parser. to be specific this line returns "True" for boolean value: JToken value = x.Value; string val = (value.ToString()); The json is  { "Bool" : "true"}

Comment: Here: `value.ToString()` -> that's your code, isn't it? This is what is changing it to `True`.

Comment: Darin, I have the exact same issue, and I'm not invoking `.ToString()`. How do you explain this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42354116/2112866 ?

Answer (score 0):

One could use anonymous types and no worry about case sensitivity of boolean type variables

```
public static void Main()
{
    bool a = true;
    JObject c = JObject.FromObject(new {BoolParam= a});
    Console.WriteLine(c);   
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "BoolParam": true
}
```