# How to deserialize Booleans from JSON case-insensitive?

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization

I'm having some difficulties in deserializing a Boolean from a json. I need that the value can be case insensitive (`faLSe`, `tRUE`, etc) and if it's an invalid value (ex: `qwerty`) I'll return a null. I've created a custom converter:

```
public class NullableBooleanJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        // Handle only boolean types.
        return objectType == typeof(bool?);
    }
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        string value = reader?.Value?.ToString();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (bool.TryParse(value, out bool deserializedValue))
        {
            return deserializedValue;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
    }
}
```

And I'm using the code like this:

```
JsonSerializerSettings setting = new JsonSerializerSettings
    { Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { this.converter } };

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<bool?>("false", setting).Should().BeFalse();
```

and this works, but if I have on the last line:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<bool?>("faLSE", setting).Should().BeFalse();
```

The test fails with the message:

> TestName threw exception:
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error parsing boolean value. Path '', line 1, position 2

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<bool?>` cannot tolerate those case changes.  Why don't you just [`.ToLower`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tolower?view=netframework-4.8) the string you want to deserialize first?

Comment: Perhaps lowercase the `value` just before `TryParse` ?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I can't do that because this will be a bigger json and I don't want to alter the other string values

Comment: Then only alter the boolean ones.  That should be easy enough to do.

Comment: Your problem is that `faLSE` is not well-formed JSON, because `faLSE` is not a JSON token.  For comparison `"faLSE"` would be well-formed JSON because `"faLSE"` is a well-formed JSON string.  While the converter can change how the JSON is deserialized, it cannot change how the JSON is *parsed* by `JsonTextReader`, and it is `JsonTextReader` that throws on malformed JSON.

Comment: See: [Json.Net boolean parsing issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19011041): *No, you have to produce valid JSON when saving if you want to be able to later deserialize it with a JSON serializer such as Newtonsoft JSON. So fixing your saving routing is the right way to go here.*

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code of [DeserializeObject](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConvert.cs) it uses the JsonTextReader class to parse the Json. If you look at the source code of [JsonTextReader](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs) it parses only "true" (if first char is a lowercase t) or "false" (if first char a lowercase f) strings (row 1720), throwing an exception in any other case.

The simplest way to realize what you need is to download the full Newtonsoft.Json source code, add a String.ToLower to ParseTrue and ParseFalse methods in JsonTextReader.cs, recompile and use the new dll in your project.

Comment: I must take back what I wrote, the ParseTrue and ParseFalse methods parse the exact lowercase value (they do not parse a value and then you can convert it to lowercase). You have to add a case insensitive overload to the methods [MatchValueWithTrailingSeparator](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/e82421145b649bed5c10b1efa36a8ce26cd866a3/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs#L2389) and MatchValue and call them from ParseTrue and ParseFalse. A little bit more more complicated, but it can be done.

Comment: Just for your information the [JSON specification](https://www.json.org/) (see value diagram) states precisely that only "true" or "false" are possible values for booleans. Why on earth do you have such a malformed JSON ?